# Automation Error with Range.Recordset method

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running into an issue when executing this line of code, that is contained in a userform:

```
 Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
 Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

 'omitting the queryString and connection parameters - I'm highly certain 
  the issue doesn't lie there

 RS.Open queryString, cn

 'Declare the object
 Dim classCutCells As Range

 'The next 2 lines are 1 in the actual code, just broke it up here for readability
 Set classCutCells = reisWS.Range(reisWS.cells(classCutRow, classCutCol),  _
     _ reisWS.cells(classCutRow + RS.RecordCount, classCutRow + RS.Fields.Count))

 'The following line produces the error
 classCutCells.CopyFromRecordset (RS)
```

When the click event goes off, I get this error:

```
Run-time error '430': Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface.
```

My current references include:

```
Visual Basic for Applications
Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library
OLE Automation
Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library
Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)
Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Exentisibility 5.3
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.0 Library
```

When I step in to debug, and pass classCutCells.CopyFromRecordset (RS) into the immediate window, the code works without a hitch, and the data is dropped into desired range.  I'm thinking this could be a reference issue, but have not found anything online after a few days of looking.  Any ideas?

Comment: What type of declaration has `RS`?

Comment: @lowak RS is ADODB.Recordset - updated the code above.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently when you call the CopyFromRecordset(RS) method with parentheses, it expects a variant.  I moved the RS out of the parentheses and now it works.  If only I had gotten a type error instead of this automation error this would've been solved last week.

Comment: Yes, spurious parentheses around calling parameters in VBA follow the traditional interpretation as being a request to make a copy of the parameter (usually to protect it from modification by the subroutine being called).  This can only work for an object if there is an interface to make a shallow-copy of the object.  This is why it failed, not because it was a Variant.